# Menu should disappear when clicked somewhere else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have a  `div` which should be visible, whenever a button is clicked. It's like a menu. Afterwards, it should disappear (toggle), when the button is clicked again  or when the user clicks somewhere else on the page (whole body).

In my current approach, the menu constantly toggles, so both functions (see below) are being triggered.

```
$("#b1").click(function() {
  $("#menu").toggle("slide");
});

$("body").click(function() {
  if ($("#menu").is(":visible")) {
    $("#menu").toggle("slide");
  }
});
```

How should I improve my code, so that the menu only disappears when the button is clicked again or when the user clicks somewhere else?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wru8mvxt/).

Comment: I know this is not directly related to what you are asking but rather than use `toggle` i would use `slideToggle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(window)` to attach the event, then you can close the menu anywhere.

```
$("#b1").click(function() {
  $("#menu").toggle("slide");
   return false;
});

$(window).click(function() {
  if ($("#menu").is(":visible")) {
    $("#menu").toggle("slide");
  }
});
```

Check demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wru8mvxt/5/

Comment: I noticed that if clicking *inside* the menu that also makes it disappear. Is there a way to make the contents of the menu exempt from the click rule?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `e.target` and check whenever it's not the menu or the button which got clicked. Otherwise the menu closed even on the button click or on a click inside.

```
$("#b1").click(function() {
    $("#menu").slideDown();
});

$("body").click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is("#b1") && $("#menu").is(":visible")) {
        $("#menu").slideUp();
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

If you want the menu to stay even on click inside, just add `&& !$(e.target).is("#menu")` to the `if` condition.

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/wru8mvxt/4/)**

Comment: I checked the demo, it didn't work well, sometimes it doesn't close when you click again

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default action of the anchor tag. See [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wru8mvxt/12/), the Hyperlink won't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code looks good.. I see one problem when you click on menu it will be hide.

```
$("#b1").click(function() {
  $("#menu").toggle("slide");
  return false; // prevent to pass click event to body
});

$("body").click(function() {
  if ($("#menu").is(":visible")) {
    $("#menu").toggle("slide");
  }
});

$("#menu").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I have edited my answer for prevent to pass click event to body when click on button

Comment: Check I have updated you jsfiddle code.. thanks  https://jsfiddle.net/wru8mvxt/8/

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    $("#b1").click(function() {
event.stopPropagation();
  $("#menu").toggle("slide");
});

$("body").click(function() {
if(!$(event.target).closest('#menu').length){
if ($("#menu").is(":visible")) {
    $("#menu").toggle("slide");
  }
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will solve your issue. You can use **e.target** property to find whether user clicked on button or outside button. When user click on button **b1** it enters both **b1 click event** and **body click event**. So if in order to find where the user is clicked you can use **event.target** property.

1. Clicking the button will toggle the menu visibility.
2. Clicking outside the button will close the menu if it is opened.

   ```
    $("#b1").click(function() {
       $("#menu").toggle("slide");
       $("#b1").text() == "hide menu" ? $("#b1").text("show menu") : $("#b1").text("hide menu");
   });

   $("body").click(function(e) {
     if (!$(e.target).is("#b1") && $("#menu").is(":visible")) {
       $("#menu").slideUp();
     } 
     else {
       e.preventDefault();
     }
   });
   ```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aruncm/wru8mvxt/7/)

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default action of the anchor tag. See [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wru8mvxt/11/), the Hyperlink won't work anymore.

Comment: @user1170330 Yes you are right.  but you can remove e.preventdefault(); then also the code will work. Change href to href="https://jsfiddle.net/". Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/aruncm/wru8mvxt/14/

Answer (score 0):

You have to do following changes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#b1").click(function(e) {
        $("#menu").slideToggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('#menu, #menu *')) {
           $("#menu").slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```